# ESLint issue: JSX not allowed in files in Typescript files

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have .tsx files with jsx inside, but I'm getting this error in VSCode:

`JSX not allowed in files with extension '.tsx'eslintreact/jsx-filename-extension`

I added this to my package.json to fix it:

**Package.json:**

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "rules": {
      "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
        1,
        {
          "extensions": [
            ".tsx",
            ".jsx"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Add this rule to your `.eslintrc.json` file:

```
"react/jsx-filename-extension": "off"
```